# HTTP Post request and parsing the response in Java

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient, httpresponse

I am trying to create a simple post request to a web API and parse the response received. After quite a lot of search, I was able to come up with the following code:

```
public class access {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://xxxxx/RSAM_API/api/Logon");

    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

 // Request parameters and other properties.
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserId", "xxxxxx"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "xxxxxxx"));

    try {
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

 //Execute and get the response.
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
       String line;
       while(null !=(line=rd.readLine())){

       System.out.println(line);
       }

   }

   catch (Exception e){

       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

}

In the above code, I am doing an post request to the URL login endpoint. the response I see after parsing it is:

```
An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator with this error id, 26225
```

I am able to login to the URL through the browser manually. Not sure where I am going wrong in the code.

Is my approach correct in the first place? Can I be sure that my code is right? If it is, why is the response an error?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Content -Type should be x-www-urlencoded

Comment: thanks for the comment, how do urlencode it?

Comment: Try get rid of the line setting Content-Type.

Comment: Also what does error id 26225 mean, actually?

Comment: wow! that worked! thanks a lot! @jingx Not sure about the error code, must be something specific to the API. doesn't matter now anyway ;)

Comment: I think it's `Content-Type` with a capital `T` and not a small `t`. Also as rollback said, it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as you are using `UrlEncodedFormEntity`